# How to paginate SyncFusion Grid converting DataTable to IEnumerable

Tags: c#, sql, .net, winforms

I have the following problem.
I'm creating a small app that allows the user to view, edit and insert data (were allowed) from tables in a SQL Server DB. I'm currently using SyncFusion DataGrid to visualize the DataTable that results from a SQL Connection. The thing is that I want to paginate it because there are lots of rows, but the SyncFusion pager does not support DataTable, only IEnumerable (or ObservableCollection) and I tried converting de DT to IE but it does not work (it returns three weird rows). I saw some examples that used models for the tables, but the problem is that there are lots of tables in the DB that I'm using and I'm trying to keep everything as generic as possible so it can work for every table (for example the queries to select data are with a *, not column names because I do not have access to them). Is there any solution or better way to implement this? I'll add the code that updates the grid just in case.

```cs
private void UpdateGrid(string tabla, string filtros)
        {
            string query = "";
            SqlConnection conn = myConnections.GetConnection();

            if (filtros.Length == 0)
            {
                query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 250 * FROM {0}", tabla);
            }
            else if (filtros.Length > 1)
            {
                query = string.Format("SELECT TOP 250 * FROM {0} WHERE {1}", tabla, filtros);
            }

            using (conn)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    sda.Fill(ds);
                    DataTable table = ds.Tables[0];
                    tableGrid.DataSource = table;

                    string checkEditable = string.Format("select * from ListadoTablas where tableName = '{0}'", NombreTabla);
                    SqlCommand checkEditableCommand = new SqlCommand(checkEditable, conn);

                    SqlDataReader sqlReader = checkEditableCommand.ExecuteReader();

                    while (sqlReader.Read())
                    {
                        if (sqlReader["editable"].ToString() == "YES")
                        {
                            tableGrid.AllowEditing = true;
                            label1.Text = "Editable";
                            label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.RoyalBlue;
                            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                        }
                        else if (sqlReader["editable"].ToString() == "NO")
                        {
                            tableGrid.AllowEditing = false;
                            label1.Text = "No editable";
                            label1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.DarkRed;
                            label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.WhiteSmoke;
                        }
                    }

                    conn.Close();
                }
                catch (SqlException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: https://help.syncfusion.com/windowsforms/gridgrouping/paging The GridGroupingcontrol seems to allow datatables.